# angularjs return json data blank no error message returned

Tags: json, angularjs

I have the following code....it all works. I am testing that when the person enters in an invalid userid/password that a 404 comes back and want to intercept the message I come back with...here is the angular code. Where/how do I get the httpresponsemessage that I wrote in the api controller? data is showing up as blank....would the webapi code help as well?

```
DataFactory.checkPW(userid, password).success(function()
{
  (function(data, status, headers, config)
    {
        //do stuff
    }
  )();
}).error(function(data, status, headers, config)
{
  //data shows up undefined
  //status shows 404 correctly
  //header information shows correctly
  //config shows up undefined

});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two kinds of interceptors (and two kinds of rejection interceptors):

```
request: interceptors get called with a http config object. The function is free to modify the config object or create a new one. The function needs to return the config object directly, or a promise containing the config or a new config object.
requestError: interceptor gets called when a previous interceptor threw an error or resolved with a rejection.
response: interceptors get called with http response object. The function is free to modify the response object or create a new one. The function needs to return the response object directly, or as a promise containing the response or a new response object.
responseError: interceptor gets called when a previous interceptor threw an error or resolved with a rejection.

// register the interceptor as a service
$provide.factory('myHttpInterceptor', function($q, dependency1, dependency2) {
  return {
    // optional method
    'request': function(config) {
      // do something on success
      return config;
    },

    // optional method
   'requestError': function(rejection) {
      // do something on error
      if (canRecover(rejection)) {
        return responseOrNewPromise
      }
      return $q.reject(rejection);
    },



    // optional method
    'response': function(response) {
      // do something on success
      return response;
    },

    // optional method
   'responseError': function(rejection) {
      // do something on error
      if (canRecover(rejection)) {
        return responseOrNewPromise
      }
      return $q.reject(rejection);
    }
  };
});
```

Code to add interceptor:

```
module.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {  
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('myHttpInterceptor');
}]);
```

This way you can customize your $http request and response.